# Find method from annotation

Tags: java, reflection

It is possible in Java to find a method from its annotations? 
For instance:

```
@Named("Qty") 
public getQty()
{
    return _quantity;
}

@Named("Qty")
public void setQty(long qty)
{
    _quantity = qty;
}
```

I know that both are annotated as "Qty", how can retrieve the setter method for example on runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Find all the methods annotated with `@Named` with the argument `Qty`, then look for a method named `getQty`, or from the list of annotated methods, check for the getter prefix.

Comment: Like Joop mentions, it is quite costly. Do u have any alternate implementation? It might not necessarily be reflection based.

Comment: If you need to locate a method based on an annotation parameter, I don't see what your options are. You could annotate properties instead and avoid having two annotations for what's essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is costly, first use on the Class getDeclaredMethods, for the Method get its Named annotation and then inspect the method name for "get[A-Z]" or "is[A-Z]". Better to tackle the problem in some other manner.

Comment: I am open to suggestions. The idea is bsed on the keyword "Qty" i would like to easily retrive the getter and setter. I heard of something called java bean properties do u think that can help?

Comment: You could look at JPA, like **eclipseLink**, http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html. O/R mappings from database to java classes is the only comparable application out there. This is somewhat in the category java bean properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection.

Use [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and [Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) to iterate over the methods.  Use the [getAnnotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getAnnotation%28java.lang.Class%29) method to determine if a method has the annotation.

```
Named attr = method . getAnnotation ( Named . class ) ;
if ( ( attr != null ) && ( attr . value == "Qty" ) ) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

using the [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library, you can do something like this:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.package", new MethodAnnotationsScanner());
Set<Method> namedMethods = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(Names.class);
//or even
Set<Method> qtyMethods = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(
        new Named() {
            public String value() { return "Qty"; } 
            public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() { return Named.class; }
        });
```

Then, it's easy to get just the setter methods using conventional java reflection, although Reflections can also help you here:

```
import static org.reflections.ReflectionsUtils.*;
Set<Method> setterMethods = getAll(methods, withPrefix("set"));
```